# Где вызвать AsynckTask чтобы отправить запрос только при первом запуске ?  [Заркыт]

Tags: android-asynctask, java

При первом запуске приложения нужно отправить запрос, который вернёт пользователю ID, с кодом проблем нет. Подскажите правильно ли будет это реализовать в onCreate, чтобы это происходило только единожды за всё время существования приложения? Если да, то вызывать ли оттуда и сам запрос и AsyncTask и parsingDataInView? А если нет - то ГДЕ прописать всю логику?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. в настройках храним ИД
2. если она не пустая, значит запрос отправдять не надо
3. если пустая надо
4. да, можно в онкриейт вызывать

Comment: Gorets, спасибо!